# In Jade how is this interpreted ? <%= lastName %>

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, pug

I currently have my code like this but the first name appears the way it is being shown. I am trying to figure out what this is in jade, because this is not right.

Jade File

```
div.centerContent
    script(type="text/javascript", src="/js/main.js")

    h4 User goes here with equal before it no space
        div#user
            p!= "<%=firstName%>"
            | <%=lastName%>
            p!="<%= email %>"
            p <%=phone%>
            p <%=birthday%>
            button.edit Edit



    script(id="userTemplate", type ="text/template")
            p <%=firstName%> <%=lastName%>
            p <%=email%>
            p <%=phone%>
            p <%=birthday1%>
            button.edit Edit

    script(id="userEditTemplate", type ="text/template")
        div
            form(action="#")
                input(type="text", class="firstName", value="<%= firstName %>") input(type="text", class="lastName", value="<%= lastName %>")
                input(type="email", class="email", value="<%= email %>")
                input(type="date", class="birthday", value="<%= birthday %>")
            button.save Save
            button.cancel Cancel
    hr
```

Here I will include my main.js file maybe I am doing something wrong there.

main.js

```
(function () {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Templates: {},
        Router: {}

    };

    // MODEL
    App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            firstName: 'first',
            lastName: 'last',
            email: 'Email',
            phone: '222',
            birthday: 'date'
        },

        validate: function (attrs) {
            if (!attrs.firstName) {
                return 'You must enter a real first name.';
            }
            if (!attrs.lastName) {
                return 'You must enter a real last name.';
            }
            if (attrs.email.length < 5) {
                return 'You must enter a real email.';
            }
            if (attrs.phone.length < 10 && attrs.phone === int) {
                return 'You must enter a real phone number, if you did please remove the dash and spaces.';
            }
            if (attrs.city.length < 2) {
                return 'You must enter a real city.';
            }
        },

        initialize: function() {
             user.on('invalid', function (model, invalid) {
                console.log(invalid);
            });
        }

    });



    //VIEW
    App.Views.User = Backbone.View.extend({
        model: App.Models.User,
        //tagName: 'div',
        //id: 'user',
        //className: 'userProfile',
        template: _.template($("#userTemplate").html()),
        editTemplate: _.template($("#userEditTemplate").html()),

        initialize: function (){

        }

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            'click button.edit': 'editProfile',
        //  'click button.save': 'saveEdits',
            'click button.cancel': 'cancelEdits'
        },

        editProfile: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.editTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));

        }, 


        cancelEdits: function() {
            this.render();
        }

    });
    //start history service
    Backbone.history.start();

    var user = new App.Views.User({el: 'div #user'});
    user.render();
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Jade sees, `"<%= firstName %>"` is just a `String` literal. But, it will HTML encode it:

```
<input type="text" class="firstName" value="&lt;%= firstName %&gt;">
```

To keep the value as-is, add a `!` before the `=` to skip encoding.

```
input(type="text", class="firstname", value!="<%= firstName %>")
```

```
<input type="text" class="firstName" value="<%= firstName %>">
```

From the [documenation](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#code):

> Code buffered by `=` is escaped by default for security, however to output unescaped return values you may use `!=`:
>
> ```
> p!= aVarContainingMoreHTML
> ```

---

Also note that, [if you're using an older version of Jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#announcement), the contents of `script` elements may be treated in whole as text literals.

> Jade version 0.31.0 deprecated implicit text only support for scripts and styles. To fix this all you need to do is add a `.` character after the script or style tag.

Before 0.31.0, your view would render as (*abridged*):

```
<script id="userEditTemplate" type="text/template">
    div.userProfile
        form(action="#")
        # ...
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry quick question what if I am throwing it in a P tag like so p <%=firstName%>

Comment: @Lion789 Should work just like that, with Jade treating it as [inline HTML](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#html). But, you can also use `!=` and a `String` literal like with the attribute: `p!= "<%= firstName %>"`.

Comment: Yep have jade 0.32.0 and that is not working still just shows the whole thing as a string

Comment: There I updated my code to include the js file and the whole jade file, maybe there is an error elsewhere

Comment: @Lion789 Backbone/Underscore's template syntax, `<%= ... %>`, only fits inside the template `<script>`s. If you want to output values with Jade, such as the initial display inside `div#user`, use its [interpolation syntax](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#tag-text): `p #{firstName} #{lastName}`.

Comment: Yeah thanks it works, now I just got to figure out why it is not showing what is in the model...